# Definition of a maximum and minimum in a normed space.

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

Let $L:V \to W$ be a linear map between two normed vector space. Let $E \subseteq V$ be a compact subspace, then we know that $L$ takes on a maximum and a minimum on $E$, since $L$ is continuous and $E$ compact.

My question: what is the definition of a maximum and a minimum in normed vector spaces? As far as I know it means that the norm is maximal/minimal, so for the maximum $\vec{x}$ we have $\|f(\vec{x})\| \geq \|f(\vec{y})\|$ for all $\vec{y} \in E$, and similarly for minimum.

However, if I take this further to $\mathbb{R}$, where the norm is the absolute value $|x|$, how does this make sense? That would mean that a negative absolute minimum could become an absolute maximum if we take absolute value.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's simply wrong to say that $L$ has a maximum or a minimum. It's $||L||$ that has a max and a min. That theorem in your head " a continuous function on a compact set has a max" needs to be revised to "a real-valued continuous function on a compact set has a max".

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So in this case, is it true that if $L$ is continuous, then $\|L\|$ is also continuous? Where $\|L\|: Hom(V,W) \to \mathbb{R}$ is the operator norm.

Comment: Sorry, wait a second. If I understand it correctly, what we need is that the norm $\|\cdot\|_W$ on the vector space $W$ is continuous, this is sufficient? Then we have that $\|\cdot\| \circ L$ is continuous, and hence $\|L\| = \sup_{x \in S^{n-1}} \|Lx\| < \infty$ exists and is real-valued.

Comment: Sorry about the notation. When I wrote $||L||$ I wasn't talking about the norm of $L$. I meant to say that no, we don't know that $L$ has a max, in fact that's meaningless since the definition you ask about does not exist. What has a max is the function $x\mapsto||Lx||$.

Comment: Yes, the norm on a normed vector space is continuous. In fact it follows from the triangle inequality that $|\,||x||-||y||\,|\le||x-y||$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result that a continuous map from a compact subset of a topological space to $\mathbb{R}$ achieves its minimum and maximum values always holds, whether or not the map arises from taking the norm of a continuous map as in your question. Typically, when one talks about finding extrema of a map the range space is $\mathbb{R}$. When we talk about the min or max of a (continuous) linear map between normed vector spaces, it is implicitly assumed that we are talking about the min or max of the map $||L|| : V \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you. That explains my confusion, as in my slides they talk about this, but with the implicit assumption you mention everything makes sense.